# Class is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm quite new to Javascript. I had to switch my project to type "Module" because an import required it. However it totally broke my code.

I am using an AutoLoader to load in all my created classes:

```
const modules = new Autoloader(path.resolve('./modules'), {
    ignore: [
        'command.js',
        'service.js',
        'event.js'
    ]
});
```

Normally when I printed out modules it would look like:

```
{ commands: { invite: class Invite extends Command } }
```

Now it doesnt recognize the class any more:

```
{ commands: { invite: undefined } }
```

The autoloader loads all the classes out (for example) my commands directory.

```
const api = require('../../api');
const Command = require('./command');

class Invite extends Command {

    prefix = '/invite';

    handle(message) {
        let args = this.stripWithoutLower(message);
        if (message.isGroupMsg !== this.groupOnly) {
            return;
        }
        if (typeof args[1] !== 'undefined') {
            let inviteCode = args[1].split('/');
            if (typeof inviteCode[3] !== 'undefined') {
                this.client.joinGroup(inviteCode[3]);
            }
        }
    }
}

module.exports = Invite;
```

Normally I would use module.exports to export the class. Inside my main.js file I would them loop through the classes I've autoloaded to initiate them. For example:

```
const commandList = [];

  Object.keys(modules['commands']).forEach(key => {
        commandList.push(new modules['commands'][key](client));
    });
```

The above coded was working until I had to switch everything to type "Module". Im very new to javascript forgive me about any mis typings.

I've read online that I had to switch `module.exports` to `exports.default = Invite;` or to `export Class`. Unfortunately both didn't worked.

What error am I getting:

```
TypeError: modules.commands[key] is not a constructor
```

Comment: `module.exports = {Invite};` ?

Comment: @Bravo unfortunately not working.

Comment: "*I had to switch my project to type "Module" because an import required it.*" - you should just have transpiled that dependency instead. Also, what is `Autoloader` and how does it work? If it is a library you didn't write yourself, check its documentation about whether (and how) it supports ES6 module syntax (I doubt it does).

Comment: The autoloader is: https://github.com/specla/autoloader.